# finding roots of inequation in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm just getting into **python** so I do not really know lots of libraries of linear programming.

What I want to do is:

Setting up a polyhedron  `Ax<=b`  and finding all the solutions it has (feasible solutions & basic feasible solutions).

where A is a MxN Matrix (M rows & N columns) and b is the vector of minimal values of each restriction.

I tried getting into scipy optimizer and numpy but I have not been able to find what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: you should look into [numpy.linalg.solve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) and post here how far you got to get more specific help

Comment: sadly numpy.linealg.solve doest work becouse its made to solve Ax=b not Ax<=b

Comment: For larger matrices that can become a difficult problem with `=b`. What matrix sizes are you dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) library which has the [inequality solver](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/inequalities.html), that seems to be doing what you're asking.